# Ubuntu fails to dual boot with Windows 10 (installation error). Any advice?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, drivers, graphics, usb-installation

I have tried to install it over and over using different methods (burning software, dvd/usb) watched countless tutorials, but non of them helped.
It just simply won't install after I reboot my pc and hit Install Ubuntu.

Error message:
[image: error message]

I couldn't find anything on the internet about whether my pc is compatible or not. If anyone could tell me if they had any success with **'Asus Essentio Series'** and/or with the motherboard in it **'Asus CM6330_CM6630_CM6730_CM6830' and Graphics card 'AMD Radeon HD 7350'** would be extremely helpful!
(Cpu= Intel Core i5 3450 if it also plays a role)

Any sort of advice will also be *very* helpful :]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have an ASUS M11ad with the AMD Radeon HD 7350 and the same CPU and I'm writing this using Ubuntu right now. I am not sure if it's an "essentio" though, it appears to be an H81 motherboard.  Can you run the live usb and select "try Ubuntu"? I had a lot of trouble getting it to boot from USB, if that is the problem you are having, I may be able to help with that.

Comment: Looks like UEFI hardware. Are you dual booting and is Windows installed in UEFI to gpt partitioned drive, or BIOS/MBR? You need to install Ubuntu in same boot mode. And may need nomodeset until correct graphical driver installed. See UEFI section: https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-itand general UEFI info:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: @OrganicMarble I have tried both 'Install' and 'Try Ubuntu' but it always ends with this error message in a black background. And btw my motherboard's model is Asus cm6330_cm6630_cm6730_cm6830 
which is not in the LinuxCompatible list provided by Asus: http://dlcdnimgs.asus.com/20160129_cosmo/cosmo/websites/global/aboutASUS/OS/Linux1602.pdf   |   totally lost, and not sure what to do next :,[

Comment: @oldfred Yes, I am dual booting and windows is installed in UEFI to gpt partitioned drive. And I have tried to install Ubuntu in the same boot mode, but it just result in black screen with error msg. I have visited the sites you have linked, should I try with older version of Ubuntu? Is there a chance of it installing?

Comment: Do not know about AMD video. But have you tried nomodeset? There are multiple AMD drivers, some only work with certain cards/chips and some only work with certain versions of Linux kernel. Are you able to connect to Intel video and turn off AMD video in UEFI? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AMDGPU-Driver

Comment: @oldfred I can't, on the Installation page there is no "F6 Other options > nomodeset" it's just a black background with simple installation option (https://imgur.com/a/Gx74G) and I don't know how to disable secure boot or anything about UEFI in the firmware settings... (https://imgur.com/a/jAUfi)

Comment: The f6 is only for BIOS installs, with UEFI you have to edit grub at grub menu which is the same when you first boot actual install before you have added proprietary drivers. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132 And you have to have UEFI Secure boot off to add proprietary drivers. Some systems need UEFI update from vendor, but Microsoft requires vendors to let users turn off Secure boot (at least with Windows 8, silent on Windows 10).